# Creating a Thread without a delegate - Why this works?

Tags: c#, multithreading, delegates

The Thread class has 4 different constructores:

Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart)

Thread(ThreadStart)

Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart, Int32)

Thread(ThreadStart, Int32)

But why this following code works?

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Thread t = new Thread(count2);
        t.Start();
        count1();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void count1() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("count1: " + i);
        }
    }

    public static void count2() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Console.WriteLine("count2: " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't pass the Thread constructore a ParameterizedThreadStart-delegate or a ThreadStart-delegate. I pass only a normal count2 method. But why this works?

Comment: A bit of an addition: Visual Studio's snippets used to add code for creating delegate instances for events until the 2012 edition. Many people didn't know this feature existed because of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because the compiler automatically adds a delegate construction for you, and it infers the type of delegate.

[This page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173174%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) documents the exact feature.